# How to create a List given a variable "x" in Python?

Tags: python

Python:

I have a variable say x.
I need to create a list of name "x"

Comment: Please clarify your question. You have done so already, a little bit below, but it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Given your comment to John Machin, I believe there is a "confusion of ideas" (as in the Charles Babbage quote)... objects don't have names (a few have an attribute like `__name__` that is used for debugging purposes; lists don't). Variables are names and they point to objects. But if your variable names depend on runtime values, your code and/or design is fundamentally broken (use a dict to map e.g. strings to values or any other collection when more appropriate).

Comment: @delnan, Thank you delnan.I will be using dict instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dict.

```
mylists = {}

x = 'abhishek'
mylists[x] = []
```

That way, in `mylists` you'll have all your lists. `mylists[x]` is the list with name `x`.

Comment: Isn't your `x` a name of the string `'abishek'`?

Comment: `mylists` now looks like this: `{'abhishek': []}`. `mylists[x]` is the same as `mylists['abhishek']`

Comment: Sorry, I have framed my question incorrectly, I want to create a list using a variable's Value.

Answer (score 3):

Then just do it:

```
>>> x = 42
>>> x
42
>>> x = [x]
>>> x
[42]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [None, 0, 1, 42, 666, "Donald Duck", 3.14159, fractions.Fraction(355, 113)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need to create a generic list using a variable 'x''s value which is obtained during runtime. For e.g. x= 'temp', i need to create a list  of name 'temp'

Comment: +1. However it might be more useful for OP if you provided pi to a higher precision.

Comment: @aaronsterling: I already did, in a previous incarnation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Machin

Answer (score 1):

He wants to make a variable out of a string!
This is my interpretation of what the OP wants...

```
x = 'cat'  
*[insert magical code]*  
cat = []
```

(I think Sudhir came the closest, excepting Nosklos clever approach)
Here's a tad elaboration of Sudhirs.

```
class NewVariables:
    pass
x = "new_variable_name"
setattr(NewVariables, x, [ ])
```

Tadah!

```
>>>NewVariables.new_variable_name
[ ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you want to take

```
x = 'temp'
```

and turn x into a list with 'temp' as its first element. That is what I inferred from your question.

If you wanted to do that, then this code will turn x into a list containing 'temp':

```
>>> x = 'temp'
>>> x = [] + [x]
>>> x
['temp']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I interpreted your question:

```
def make_list(method):
    return [method.__name__]

def x():
    pass

make_list(x)
# ["x"]
```

Of course you can also accept a variable number of methods and return the names of each of them in a list:

```
def make_list_of_names(*methods):
    return [m.__name__ for m in methods]

make_list(x, str, any_function)
# ["x", "str", "any_function"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I have framed my question incorrectly, I want to create a list using a variable's Value.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'temp'
setattr(self,x,[])
getattr(self,x)
# gives []
```